# undefined row to column, group by year and month

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to change the structure data inside the data frame

```
year  month  count  reason 
2001  1     1       a
2001  2     3       b
2001  3     4       c
2005  1     4       a
2005  1     3       c
```

at new data frame should look like:

```
year  month  count  reason_a  reason_b  reason_c  
2001  1      1      1         0         0
2001  2      3      0         3         0
2001  3      4      0         0         4
2005  1      7      4         0         3
```

Is anyone can show some Python code to do it? Thank you in advance,

Comment: `pd.pivot_table()` function could split your `count` column to different columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pivot_table`:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["year","month",],values=["count"],columns="reason").reset_index().fillna(0)
df2.columns = [i[0] if i[0]!="count" else f"reason_{i[1]}" for i in df2.columns]
df2["count"] = df2.iloc[:,2:5].sum(axis=1)
print (df2)
#
   year  month  reason_a  reason_b  reason_c  count
0  2001      1       1.0       0.0       0.0    1.0
1  2001      2       0.0       3.0       0.0    3.0
2  2001      3       0.0       0.0       4.0    4.0
3  2005      1       4.0       0.0       3.0    7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

- [`DataFrame.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) - Join columns of another DataFrame.
- [`pandas.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) - Convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables.
- [`DataFrame.mul()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) - Get Multiplication of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator mul).
- [`DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) - Group DataFrame or Series using a mapper or by a Series of columns.
- [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) - Aggregate using callable, string, dict, or list of string/callables.

**Ex.**

```
dummies = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df["reason"],prefix='reason').mul(df['count'], axis=0))
f = {'count': 'sum', 'reason_a': 'first', 'reason_b': 'first', 'reason_c': 'last'}
df1 = dummies.groupby(['year','month'],sort=False,as_index=False).agg(f)
print(df1)
```

**O/P:**

```
   year  month  count  reason_a  reason_b  reason_c
0  2001      1      1         1         0         0
1  2001      2      3         0         3         0
2  2001      3      4         0         0         4
3  2005      1      7         4         0         3
```